# 500 - Internal server error. how i can solve it in asp.net MVC 3 on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I deployed a mvc 3 project.
The server gave an `error 500 - Internal server error`. Nothing else.

How can I get more detail about it. How can I know the reason behind it, because there is nothing going wrong in my code in my development machine.

Since I just have FTP access, is there a way for me to create a log and get all the information about the error in detail.

are their any possible thing i can do that i can see the error in my browser. no problem because i deploy on testing domain.

Comment: @moby (their != there && detailed !=detail)

Comment: When are you getting this error? On any page or just the particular one?

Answer (score 1):

You will get a 500 error if the web.config xml is invalid. Find out if is invalid by opening IIS Manager, and for the site double click on one of the features (Authorization, HTTP Redirect). If the xml is invalid, it will display a message box with an error and a line number.

If the web config is ok, configure customErrors so you can the errors.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx

This might display some more detailed information.

Comment: the article is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure is ASP.Net MVC installed on the server? or Is the correct version of IIS installed on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the data is out of ajax like data_.

```
var data_ = { indexNum: index };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/ExamsById",     
    data: data_,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {   
        $(".cont-exams").slideToggle();     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the data is out of ajax like data_.

```
var data_ = { indexNum: index };
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/ExamsById",

    data: data_,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {

        $(".cont-exams").slideToggle();

    }



});
```